# Bar chart datasetname bold in jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart, bar-chart

In my `Barchart`,how to add dataset value text in bold, i tried

```
rangeAxis.setTickLabelFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
```

that's work in horizontally fine but in vertically didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

try for vertically

```
domainAxis.setTickLabelFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
```